# 403 Forbidden - Tweepy Authentication error when attempting to access tweet/user data with client.get_user()

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy, http-status-code-403

```
import tweepy
import os

api_key = os.getenv('TWI_API_KEY')
api_key_secret = os.getenv('TWI_API_KEY_SECRET')
bearer_token = os.getenv('TWI_BEARER_TOKEN')
access_token = os.getenv('TWI_ACCESS_TOKEN')
access_token_secret = os.getenv('TWI_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token,
                       consumer_key=api_key,
                       consumer_secret=api_key_secret,
                       access_token=access_token,
                       access_token_secret=access_token_secret)

user_get = client.get_user(username='twitterusers')
user_id = user_get.data.id
print(user_id)
```

Above, is the code I've written so far in my attempt to create a Twitter bot that replies to a specific user's most recent tweet, however I did not make it far as I receive the following error when attempting to use the Client.get_user() method to retrieve a user's Twitter ID:

`tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.`

I went into the Twitter developer portal --> user authentication settings, and I made sure that the app permissions were set to 'Read and write'.

I then tried regenerating all of my keys and tokens and made sure that there was no issue with the validity of the credentials themselves.

I further confirmed it's not an issue with the keys or tokens when I found I was able to successfully tweet without receiving any errors using the following code.

```
import tweepy
import os

api_key = os.getenv('TWI_API_KEY')
api_key_secret = os.getenv('TWI_API_KEY_SECRET')
bearer_token = os.getenv('TWI_BEARER_TOKEN')
access_token = os.getenv('TWI_ACCESS_TOKEN')
access_token_secret = os.getenv('TWI_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token,
                       consumer_key=api_key,
                       consumer_secret=api_key_secret,
                       access_token=access_token,
                       access_token_secret=access_token_secret)

response = client.create_tweet(text='Testing!')

print(response)
```

I tried changing the credentials passed to tweepy.Client(), first using the bearer_token only. Passing the bearer_token exclusively, as I have seen done in some examples, I received the same 403 Error as mentioned above.

Then I tried passing the consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret.
In this case, I receive the following 401 error:

`tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized`

`Unauthorized`

In either case, I am unable to utilize Client.get_user()

Comment: I am facing the same issue now. The app was working fine untill a week ago and then i start getting the same error. I also tried to get a new bearer token and tried to authenticate it with that but i still get the same error. Not sure what the problem is.. have you found the solution?

Comment: @akshaypai
I have not found a solution : ( 
After not receiving any suggestions I did some more digging and I believe the problem is related to a policy change by Twitter regarding how they allow non-paying users to interact with their API. I believe to use these functionalities you must now pay for access. I'm not 100% certain of this but similar issues I saw others having all  occurring around the time the policy change was rolled out leads me to believe that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of twitter policy change where in the free tier, there is no way for us to pull tweets, we can only do that if we have a basic subscription which is 100$ per month now.
Details can be found here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/twitter-api